# How can I translate a placeholder in angular 4 with jhi-translate?

Tags: json, angular, jhipster, placeholder, angular-translate

Does anyone know how to translate a placeholder in angular 4 using jhi-translate? I have saved the translations in the Json files in i18n.

My idea below does not work
.

```
placeholder="jhiTranslate='main.form.text'"
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
placeholder="{{'main.form.text' | translate}}"
```

Comment: It uses `ngx-translate`, not `jhi-translate` but it works. Thanks)

Answer (score -3):

You should try this:

```
<span jhiTranslate="main.form.text"></span>
```

Comment: The person already mentioned that he tried `jhiTranslate`. The answer does not provide any additional information.

Comment: Just take a look at the syntax he wrote and compare with mine. In my case `jhiTranslate` is an attribute and it should be used this way.

Comment: Can Placeholder have attributes?

Comment: From my side it looks like this placeholder is an attribute. Without the full code it's really hard to guess